# Doubt In A simple integral using complex numbers

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

Suppose we have $\int_{0}^{\infty}{{e^{-sx}}\sin x} \,dx$

The integral of this is just the imaginary part of $\int_{0}^{\infty}{{e^{-sx}}{e^{ix}}} \,dx$

This can further be written as $\frac{e^{-x(s-i)}}{i-s}$ or $\frac{e^{x(i-s)}}{i-s}$ with the limits from 0 to infinity. In the first case when we substitute the upper limit as infinity we will get $0$ (as $e^{-x}$ will tend to $0$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$) but in the second case we will $\infty$ when we substitute the upper limit.
Can anyone please point out my misunderstanding in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We always have $$\exp(-x(s-i))=\exp(x(i-s))$$

It value depends on the **sign** of $s$.

\begin{align}\lim_{x \to \infty} \exp(-x(s-i))&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \exp(ix)\exp(-sx)\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty} (\cos x+ i \sin x) \exp(-sx)\end{align}

If $s$ is positive, then $\exp(-sx)$ tends to zero and since the norm of $\exp(ix)$ is bounded, we have the whole expression tends to zero.

When it is non-positive, try to take particular subsequence to show that it doesn't converge.